# What is the difference between a service account and a context in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

What are the practical differences between the two? When should I choose one over the other?

For example if I'd like to give a developer in my project access to just view the logs of a pod. It seems both a service account or a context could be assigned these permissions via a RoleBinding.

Comment: context is used to point kubectl to one specific cluster, so from point of view they has different scope

Comment: Not sure I understand. A service account is also bound to a single cluster?

Comment: Can you give an example of the "context" you are referring to? There can be a securityContext on a container but they don't directly relate to RBAC. The other context @c4f4t0r is referencing is kubectl configuration, which doesn't have much relation either.

Answer (score 4):

**What is Service Account?**

From [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/)

> User accounts are for humans. Service accounts are for processes,
>   which run in pods.
>
> User accounts are intended to be global...Service
>   accounts are namespaced.

**Context**

`context` related to `kubeconfig` file(`~/.kube/config`). As you know `kubeconfig` file is a yaml file, the section `context` holds your `user/token` and `cluster` references. `context` is really usefull when you have multiple cluster, you can define all your `cluster`s and `user`s in single `kubeconfig` file, then you can switch between them with help of context (Example: `kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo use-context dev-frontend`)

From [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: fake-ca-file
    server: https://1.2.3.4
  name: development
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://5.6.7.8
  name: scratch
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: frontend
    user: developer
  name: dev-frontend
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: storage
    user: developer
  name: dev-storage
- context:
    cluster: scratch
    namespace: default
    user: experimenter
  name: exp-scratch
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: developer
  user:
    client-certificate: fake-cert-file
    client-key: fake-key-file
- name: experimenter
  user:
    password: some-password
    username: exp
```

You can above, there are 3 contexts, holds references of `cluster` and `user`.

> ..if I'd like to give a developer in my project access to just view the
>   logs of a pod. It seems both a service account or a context could be
>   assigned these permissions via a RoleBinding.

That correct, you need to create `service account`, `Role`(or `ClusterRole`), `RoleBinding`(or `ClusterRoleBinding`) and generate `kubeconfig` file that contains service account `token` and give it your developer.

I have a [script to generate `kubconfig` file,](https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/spinnaker/kubeconfig_generator.sh) takes service account name argument. Feel free to check out

**UPDATE:**

If you want to create `Role` and `RoleBinding`, [this might help](https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/spinnaker/spinnaker_sa.yaml)

Answer (score 1):

**Service Account**: A service account represents an identity for processes that run in a pod. When a process is authenticated through a service account, it can contact the API server and access cluster resources. If a pod doesn’t have an assigned service account, it gets the default service account.

When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is automatically assigned the default service account in the same namespace and you can access the API from inside a pod using automatically mounted service account credentials.

**Context**: A context is just a set of access parameters that contains a Kubernetes cluster, a user, and a namespace.

The current context is the cluster that is currently the default for kubectl and all kubectl commands run against that cluster.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different concepts. A context most probably refers to an abstraction relating to the `kubectl` configuration, where a context can be associated with a service account.

For some reason I assumed a `context` was just another method of authentication.